# Multiple Credentials and Secrets for Google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api-client

If I'm using more than 1 Google API (Drive and Calendar) in my Rails app, will I need different credentials set up on the dev console and thus different credential.yaml and secret.json files (1 of each for each API)?

Comment: Thats pretty much up to you - you can have one Google project with multiple APIs enabled, or multiple Google projects with different APIs.   I believe each project has its own credentials unless you use a system account

Comment: @JohnNaegle well, it's a single Google project in a single Rails app with different APIs enabled